# Dataframe calculation using groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to calculate an average for a column using dataframe group by and am getting an incorrect result. I roughly know why it is doing it, I just don't know exactly how to fix it. I am trying to get the average plays of a team's opponent - right now, it calculates correctly, but is putting it in the wrong row. For example, Green Bay played Chicago and Minnesota - their opponents ran an average of 62.5 plays. Chicago played Green Bay and Denver, who ran an average of 66.5 plays. Therefore, in my example, Chicago's opponents per play should be 66.5 while GB's is 62.5. Unfortunately, it is reversing these. I think it is grouping by Defense, and writing the average to the first row which in this case is actually their opponent. This is kind of hard to explain so I'm attaching images to help show what is happening.

I also know I can probably write a function as opposed to the way the code is structured now, and that will likely be my task tomorrow, but for the time being here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import numpy as np

beginningTime = time.time()

dfTeam = pd.read_csv("TEAM.csv")


dfSchedule = pd.read_csv("SCHEDULE.csv")

dfTandS = pd.merge(dfTeam, dfSchedule, on='gid', how='inner')

dfTandS['Defense'] = np.where(dfTandS.tname == dfTandS.v, dfTandS.h, dfTandS.v)

dfTandS.to_excel("Team and Schedule.xlsx", index=False)

dfTeamRankings = pd.read_excel("Team Rankings.xlsx")
dfTandS['Total Plays'] = dfTandS['ra'] + dfTandS['pa'] + dfTandS['sk']
dfTandS['Passing Plays'] = dfTandS['pa'] + dfTandS['sk']


dfTeamRankings['Plays Per Game'] = dfTandS.groupby('tname')['Total Plays'].transform('mean')
dfTeamRankings['Rank - Plays Per Game'] = dfTeamRankings['Plays Per Game'].rank(ascending=False, method='min')
```

This is where it is not working quite right

```
dfTeamRankings['Opponent Plays Per Game'] = dfTandS.groupby('Defense')['Total Plays'].transform('mean')
dfTeamRankings['Rank - Opponent Plays Per Game'] = dfTeamRankings['Opponent Plays Per Game'].rank(ascending=False, method='min')


dfTeamRankings['Passing Plays Per Game'] = dfTandS.groupby('tname')['Passing Plays'].transform('mean')
dfTeamRankings['Rank - Passing Plays Per Game'] = dfTeamRankings['Passing Plays Per Game'].rank(ascending=False, method='min')


dfTeamRankings['Rushing Plays Per Game'] = dfTandS.groupby('tname')['ra'].transform('mean')
dfTeamRankings['Rank - Rushing Plays Per Game'] = dfTeamRankings['Rushing Plays Per Game'].rank(ascending=False, method='min')

dfTeamRankings.to_excel('Team Rankings.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image: Structure of initial data]

[image: Improper Output as numbers are flipped between the two teams]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out what would work best without the data but this could potentially help:

```
dfTeamRankings['Opponent Plays Per Game'] = dfTandS.groupby('Defense').agg(np.mean)['Total Plays']
```

Comment: When I ran your code it just gave two empty columns. I'm doing something very similar to what you have shown, but it's not grouping the way I expected. For example, line 1 is GB and the defense is Chicago. So it is grouping by Chicago as it is supposed to, but then it is writing the result to line 1 where the Defense is - however, I need it to match up the column defense and tname, and write the result there. I don't know how to tell it to get the result and then write to the proper rows.